# Не работает клавиатура в приложениях и играх через Wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, клавиатура, wine

В некоторых приложениях, установленных через Wine, не работает клавиатура. В некоторых(установлено через стим, который установлен через wine) клава не подает признаков жизни. При изменении раскладки в игре, показывает что это клавиша(нажимается w,a,s,d,e,f,r,q,t) показывает что клавиша <">. В некоторых приложениях вообще не работает. В некоторых с задержкой или через раз.

Comment: *клава сама рабочая

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/547430/keyboard-not-working-with-games-in-wine

Comment: Спасибо, начало работать

Answer (score 2):

1. Откройте «configure wine»
2. Выберите Windows 8 в поле.
3. Откройте вкладку graphics
4. Снимите флажок «разрешить диспетчеру окна управлять окнами» и затем
   поставьте заново этот флажок,после чего примените изменения нажав ok.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу посоветовать свой способ,при установке контр страйка такая же беда была,дошел к этому способу чисто интуитивно,заходите в домашнюю папку нажимаете  ctrl h появляються скрытые папки,затем wine,dosdevices,с,conter-strike,valive,находите файл config.cfg,затем проводите манипуляцию не поддающуюся моей логике,находите w ,это движение вперед стираете ее и записываете ее снова,потом сохраняете изменения,заходите в игру и вуаля все работает,только если вы выходите из игры последующий вход опять предется делать то же самое,либо не выходить из игры